# Remove White Space From HTML Created From A Word Doc

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to remove the white space from a HTML file that was created from a Word Document (export to HTML) and I am still unsuccessful.
For example:

```
<p dir="ltr" class="pt-ListParagraph">
<span class="pt-000003"> </span></p>
<p dir="ltr" class="pt-Normal-000001">
<span class="pt-DefaultParagraphFont-000002">Work Instruction</span></p>
<p dir="ltr" class="pt-Normal">
<span class="pt-000000"> </span></p>
<p dir="ltr" class="pt-Normal">
<span class="pt-DefaultParagraphFont">DEFINITIONS AND ACRONYMS</span></p>
<p dir="ltr" class="pt-BodyText"><span class="pt-000004"> </span></p>
<p dir="ltr" class="pt-Normal-000005">
<span class="pt-DefaultParagraphFont-000006">DO Brief        </span>
<span class="pt-DefaultParagraphFont-000007">   </span>
```

I have tried the CSS selector `p span:empty` and `p span:blank`, which does not work because it see the white space between the `<span class="pt-000000"> </span>`.  I have tried the options generated from this post title which are unsuccessful (jQuery is not an option) - I am at a loss.  I would like to add a `.js` file in the head of the HTML to run on page load that would remove all of the white space (`<span class="pt-000000"> </span>`) that is generated when a Word Doc is converted to an HTML file.  Can anyone offer me some advice?

Removing the spans are an option. However, the span classes will be different every time depending on the export of the Word Doc requiring me to make several span.classes. I have thought about that but figured it was just a band-aid on the issue.

**UPDATE**
`window.addEventListener` did the trick:

```html
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
var spans = document.getElementsByTagName('span');
for (var i = 0; i < spans.length; i++) {
    if (spans[i].innerHTML.trim() == '') {
        spans[i].remove();
    }
}
});
```

Comment: do you want to remove `span`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [getElementsByTagName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByTagName) to retrieve a list of all the `span` elements in your HTML file. Then walk through every span element and check whether it contains only whitespace. If so, set the `innerHTML` of that span to en empty string.

Example:

```
var spans = document.getElementsByTagName('span');
for (var i = 0; i < spans.length; i++) {
    if (spans[i].innerHTML.trim() == '') {
        spans[i].remove();
    }
}
```

Updated example:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    var spans = document.getElementsByTagName('span');
    for (var i = 0; i < spans.length; i++) {
        if (spans[i].innerHTML.trim() == '') {
            spans[i].remove();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I am linking the code in the header `<link href="4.101.01.01_files/clearWS.js" type="text/javascript">`

Comment: Could you try the updated code. If you put your JavaScript in the head section, then you have to wrap your code in a ready handler.

Comment: `window.addEventListner' works only if I manually embed the script.  However, multiple files will need to use this to remove the white space.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your last comment. Do you mean that you have to put your javascript in an external file and when you link to that javascript file, the code should work? I tested the code by putting the javascript in an external file and that works as well.

Comment: Btw, the link-element is often used to link to an external css-file. To link to an external js-file, use the script-tag instead: <script type="text/javascript" src="file.js"></script>.

Comment: Yes, When I link the file, it does not work even thought the file path is correct.
UPDATE: that was my issue... danggit Bobby!  Thanks for the quick response!  This fixed the issue!

Answer (score 1):

Get all span using **[`querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)** or **[`getElementsByTagName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByTagName)**, then iterate over them using **[`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)**  and remove based on content using **[`remove()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/remove)** method.

```js
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('span')).forEach(function(ele) {
  if (!ele.textContent.trim()) ele.remove();
});

// or 

[].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('span')).forEach(function(ele) {
  if (!ele.textContent.trim()) ele.remove();
});
```

```html
<p dir="ltr" class="pt-ListParagraph">
<span class="pt-000003"> </span></p>
<p dir="ltr" class="pt-Normal-000001">
<span class="pt-DefaultParagraphFont-000002">Work Instruction</span></p>
<p dir="ltr" class="pt-Normal">
<span class="pt-000000"> </span></p>
<p dir="ltr" class="pt-Normal">
<span class="pt-DefaultParagraphFont">DEFINITIONS AND ACRONYMS</span></p>
<p dir="ltr" class="pt-BodyText"><span class="pt-000004"> </span></p>
<p dir="ltr" class="pt-Normal-000005">
<span class="pt-DefaultParagraphFont-000006">DO Brief        </span>
<span class="pt-DefaultParagraphFont-000007">   </span>
```

---

The `remove()` method only works in latest browser so use following code for instead.

```
ele.parentNode.removeChild(ele);
```

Comment: I tried adding the forEach and it did not work... I am using Chrome, but our default is I.E.
None of the options worked.

Comment: @BobbyEtheredge :  which browser are you using?

Comment: @BobbyEtheredge : check second option with slice

Comment: @BobbyEtheredge : any error in console? and which browser are you working ?

Comment: @BobbyEtheredge : inside tforEach callback try this code `ele.parentNode.removeChild(ele);`

Comment: @BobbyEtheredge :  try `[].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('span')).forEach(function(ele) {
  if (!ele.textContent.trim()) ele.parentNode.removeChild(ele);
});`

Answer (score 0):

class{ display:none; } ?
or 
class { content: ''; } maybe ?

Comment: The span classes will be different every time a document is converted which would require me to make hundreds of `span.classes {display:none;}` - so this is not a good option.

Comment: could only use span ? if not, just maybe have to try with javascript, I'll search for it